# Overlay a t-distribution to my histogram using R?

Tags: r, overlay

How can I overlay a t-density to my histogram using R? Here's my function:

```
simfun <- function(a=56.25102409,b=1.78977412,c=0.08664925,n=18,x1.sd=18.87671,x2.sd=18.87671,e.sd=18.87671) {
   X1 <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=x1.sd)
   X2 <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=x2.sd) 
   e <-  rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=e.sd)
   Z <- a+b*X1+c*X2+e 
   data.frame(X1,X2,Z)
}

statfun <- function(samples) {
    coef(lm(Z~X1+X2,data=samples))
}

library(plyr)
B=raply(1000,statfun(simfun()))

(hist(B[,2]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the last line to:

```
hist(B[,2], prob=TRUE)
```

to get the scaling correct, then do

```
curve( dt(x, df=15), add=TRUE, col='blue' )
```

changing the `df` and color to whatever values you want.

Comment: See ?curve. The `curve` function expects an expression involving "x" into which it passes a sequences of ascending values over the range of the xlim to be evaluated in the context of the expression

Comment: Ah, thanks dwin, although it still seems safer to write `from=-4, to to=4` or some such. I almost always have an object called `x` that could pollute things.

Comment: I don't think that should cause problems. I suspect that the expression will be evaluated in the environment of the `curve` function and that it will find the correct "x". Furthermore setting limits like that will not affect what "x" is found, merely the range over which it would be constructred.

Answer (score 1):

As November 2019 the way I found to get this plot is with a new plot. Apparently, using `dt` with `curve` assumes the `x` is normalized. The `df` parameter could be estimated with `fitdistr` from `MASS` package.

```
fit.t.tc <- fitdistr(B[,2], "t", hessian = TRUE)
(param.t=fit.t.tc$estimate)

dh=hist(B[,2], prob=TRUE)
#to get the scaling correct, then do
curve( dt(x, df=param.t["df"]), add=TRUE, col='blue' ) # ??
par(new = TRUE)
ss=seq(range(dh$mids)[1],range(dh$mids)[2],length.out = 1000)
x=((ss-param.t["m"])/param.t["s"])
plot(x,100*dt(x=x,df=param.t["df"]), type="l",
      col="red", lwd=3,xlab="",axes=F,ylab="")
```

[image]