# Can't make t distribution with ggplot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, distribution, normal-distribution

I have a large sample size (n=9000) and I want to plot this distribution with its confidence intervals.

Generally, I think I have to plot a t-distribution but I don't know how to plot it. Or is it because the high sample size, that I can plot a normal distribution?

How could I plot it with ggplot and how can I add a line which emphasizes the mean and confidence intervals?

Comment: Can you please make *"to plot this distribution with its confidence intervals"* more clear? 1) By to plot the distribution do you mean to plot the sample's histogram? 2) Confidence intervals of what, the sample mean?

Comment: @RuiBarradas so I have a data sample with a length of n=9000. And my task was, to calculate the confidence intervals of the mean. This was no problem (143.837,066  ≤ µ  ≤ 150.233,175). To calculate this confidence interval, I had to determine the distribution first, so I choose the t-distribution. 

So the point is, that my sample size is so big, I think that maybe I could plot a normal distribution, but I don't really know.

And I don't know, how I should plot this distribution.. t- or normal and how to program it with ggplot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overlay a t-distribution to my histogram using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103582/overlay-a-t-distribution-to-my-histogram-using-r)