# Why does the curve not plot in the existing graph?

Tags: r, statistics

I cannot understand why does not the curve plot onto the histogram. I think the formula and data are both okay. I really need help on this!!
[Data description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXDAl.png)
[Histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygxrW.png)

---

[image of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT7BF.png)

I am trying to plot a normal function curve onto the graph

Comment: A histogram and a density plot can have very different y-axes. Most likely, that simple fact is behind your issue. Plot both separately and compare the y-axes.

Comment: when iu try to plot them in different graphs, i receive an error: needed finite values in 'ylim', but i cannot find how to solve it

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19103582/overlay-a-t-distribution-to-my-histogram-using-r) shows a base R example and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688082/overlay-histogram-with-density-curve) is a ggplot solution

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: Just add `freq=FALSE` to the `hist` instruction.